# Boot FAIL Message

Tags: raspbian, boot

> "[FAIL ]startpar: service(s) returned failure: dbus … failed!"

The message shows up when boot finished. And I can still login to the Rpi.

What does this message mean and how to fix it?

Comment: After the error message, can you  login ? or cannot ?

Comment: I can login.The error message shows up at the end of boot.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not surprisingly this means that the `dbus` service failed to start.

Given that you can log in to the Pi, I'd try: `sudo service dbus start` and see whether you can start it manually, then use `dmesg` and report what the last few lines say.  However this may not work for you because I use sysv `init` (the default for older versions of Raspian) and I do not know that the default `systemd` for the current "Jessie" version at the time of writing responds to the same commands.